# ImportError: No module named 'geopy' ipython-notebook

Tags: python, geopy

currently I need to make some distance calculation. For this I am trying the following on my ipython-notebook (version 4.0.4):

```
from geopy.distance import vincenty

ig_gruendau = (50.195883, 9.115557)
delphi = (49.99908,19.84481)

print(vincenty(ig_gruendau,delphi).miles)
```

Unfortunately I receive the following error when running the code above: ImportError: No module named 'geopy'

Since I am pretty new at python, I wonder how can I install this module (without admin rights) or what other simple options I do have for this calculations?

Thanks,
ML

Comment: This error indicates that you do not have the geopy package installed. On a console (e.g. `bash` if you work on linux) execute the following command to install it `pip install geopy --user`.

Comment: activating the python environment and then installing geopy, solved the issue for me

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to install the missing module in your python installation. So you have to run the command:

```
pip install geopy
```

in your terminal. If you don't have pip, you'll have to install it using:

```
easy_install pip
```

and if both command fail with `Permission denied`, then you'll have to either launch the command as root:

```
sudo easy_install pip
sudo pip install geopy
```

or for pip, install it only for your user:

```
pip install geopy --user
```

And for future reference, whenever you get that kind of error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'XXXXX'
```

you can search for it on pypi using pip:

```
% pip search XXXXX
```

and in your case:

```
% pip search geopy
tornado-geopy (0.1.0)  - tornado-geopy is an asynchronous version of the awesome geopy library.
geopy.jp (0.1.0)       - Geocoding library for Python.
geopy.jp-2.7 (0.1.0)   - Geocoding library for Python.
geopy (1.11.0)         - Python Geocoding Toolbox
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Even if you install using `pip install` command you still have to use:

```
conda install -c conda-forge geopy
```

This command is in the anaconda server so that it gets installed in the anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

Double-check your interpreter settings.

Adding a potential solution below, especially for those running venvs through VS Code. A fresh VSC install put me back to square 1 with a number of "No Module Named" errors, which landed me on this thread.

My solution:

1. update python/PIP as covered above
2. enable official [Python extension for VSC](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python)--not [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) (as I've seen suggested in a few places<< not bashing code runner--it's just that Python extension will get you going faster, especially if you're newer to development like me.
3. Make sure your [shell is activated](https://python.land/virtual-environments/virtualenv), usually `env/bin/activate`, `poetry shell`, etc.
4. Set your interpreter. VSC confuses folks by placing a recommendation 'star' next to your latest system/pip version of Python. If you're running a venv, be sure to select the Python version installed within your virtual environment.

[image]

Hope this helps--